# Storyboard- UIScrollView Panics?

Tags: ios5, ios6, tabs, uiscrollview, scroll

I followed this tutorial from [AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboard-tutorial-create-tab-bar-controller-and-web-view/) to resolve an issue I had with my TabApplication, it is **NOT**. a webkit, I used this tactic to resolve my tab titles not displaying.
    This is an app to list bands for a local event. So You've got:

```
 TabBarController > Nav1 > RELATIONSHIP > Home
                     > Nav2 > RELATIONSHIP > ARTISTS > UIBUTTON > push to new page.
                     > etc.
```

They all work wonderfully; if I click on an artist image (UIButton) it takes me to their page. Top part is a banner (UIIMAGE) and the bottom area is a UISCROLLVIEW.

Here lies my problem: If I CLICK on the Artist Button, scroll the UIScrollView to the bottom, and it I leave the page by hitting another Tab Button I get conflict: When I tap the button to go back to the Artist list (not specified artist) It takes me where I left off and there's an awkward gap between the bottom of the UIScrollView and the Tab Bar with links.

Is there a way I can specify to return to the Artist page with the 6 UIBUTTONS? Or even GET RID of the TabBar options  on the bottom part of the screen? I don't know how to code UISCROLLVIEW, I just used Storyboard to draw the ScrollView out because this is one thing I could never work out.

```
___________________________________

|                                 |
|_________ARTIST____________NAME__|
|                                 |
|            :)                   |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                  :)             |
|_________________________________|
|                                 |
|                                 |
|   .....UISCROLLVIEW             |
|_________________________________|
|MAKE_BLANK __BAR_____NO LINKS____| Sorry for the horrible example.
```

Comment: Actually, ALL of my views (to my dismay) does this panicky glitching with UIScrollView. Is there a way I can just make it refresh the original page when I click a Tab Button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it your navigation problem is this:

On Tab 2 you have a Navigation Controller whose initial viewController is a list of artists names. If you select an artists name, you segue to a second viewController (still in Tab 2), which shows that artists details.

Now if you navigate to Tab 1, do other stuff, go back to tab 2, you want to ensure you are presented with the initial viewController with the list of artists names, whereas you are being returned to the same artist's page you had left. This leaves your app in a poorly-navigated state (with a glitchy scrollView).

So what you want to do is prevent the user from tabbing away from an artists page, so that they are forced to return to the artists list from where they *can* tab elsewhere.

You can achieve this by *presenting* the artists viewController from the initial viewController, rather than *pushing* onto the navigationController's stack of viewControllers (which I assume you are doing now).

To do this you don't actually use the navigation controller in tab2, so you might choose to get rid of it (unless you want the top navBar for other reasons).

*In code*

From artistsNamesViewController, make a button with an action:

```
- (IBAction) presentArtistsDetailViewController:(id)sender
{
     ArtistsDetailViewController* artistsDetailViewController = [ArtistsDetailViewController alloc] init];

     //set up artistsDetailViewController properties here

     [self presentViewController:artistsDetailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

*Using storyboard*

Instead of code, you can drag a segue line from the button to your artistsDetailViewController, select segue type `modal`. If you need to initialise properties in your `artistsDetailViewController`, you can do it in `prepareForSegue`

You will see that this type of navigation uses a default slide-up animation to show the new viewController, and the entire screen changes - you lose your tab bar. You can change the animation by setting the `modalTransitionStyle` property on `artistsDetailViewController`.

Navigation back is controlled by adding a 'dismiss' button, with an IBAction something like this...

```
  - (IBAction) dismiss:(id) sender
  {
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]
  }
```

Your user can now only tab away from tab 2 if they are on the initial artistsNamesViewController. You won't get a glitch in your scrollView because every time you go to an artists detail page you are recreating and reinitialising it. This doesn't address other parts of your app where you may be experiencing a problem scrollView (as you suggest in your comment), but that is a separate issue, I wanted to address your navigation logic.

You won't get a navigation bar at the top of your artistsDetailViewController this way, as the navigation controller is not involved. If you want a navigation bar, you can manually place on onto the viewController in the storyboard.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! This makes perfect sense, but when I didn't have a separate navigation controller for each view the title bar wouldn't display the name (despite it being typed on the view itself), but it lacked the tab bar on the bottom. How would I fix that?

Comment: @Techgirl-52 - I don't quite understand what you mean, but if your interface works best by keeping the navigation controller, then keep it. You can even embed your presented viewController in it's own navigation controller if need be. If it is some further issue then it's best to raise a new question.